# How to pass state between event handlers in gtk2hs

Tags: haskell, gtk2hs

I'm trying to make a toy application, just to get my head around how to write event driven programs in Haskell. What I'm trying to do is draw a line to a canvas which moves forward every time a key is pressed (so it's sort of a primordial cursor in a text editor).

My problem is I can't work out what the best way to count the number of times the user has pressed a key. Obviously I can't use a global variable like I would in an imperative program so presumably I need to pass the state around on the call stack, but in GTK execution descends into the main loop after each event handler returns and since I don't control the main loop I don't see how I can pass the changed global state from one event handler. So how can one event handler ever pass state onto another event handler?

I have a sort of partial solution here, where the keyboard event re-curries myDraw and sets it as a new the event handler. I'm not sure if this solution can be extended, or even if it's a good idea.

What's the best particle solution to this problem?

```
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Graphics.Rendering.Cairo

main :: IO ()
main= do
     initGUI
     window <- windowNew
     set window [windowTitle := "Hello World",
                 windowDefaultWidth := 300, windowDefaultHeight := 200]

     canvas <- drawingAreaNew
     containerAdd window canvas

     widgetShowAll window 
     draWin <- widgetGetDrawWindow canvas
     canvas `on` exposeEvent $ do liftIO $ renderWithDrawable draWin (myDraw 10)
                                  return False

     window `on` keyPressEvent $ onKeyboard canvas
     window `on` destroyEvent  $ do liftIO mainQuit
                                    return False

     mainGUI

onKeyboard :: DrawingArea -> EventM EKey Bool
onKeyboard canvas = do 
  liftIO $ do drawWin <- widgetGetDrawWindow canvas
              canvas `on` exposeEvent $ do liftIO $renderWithDrawable drawWin (myDraw 20)
                                           return False
              widgetQueueDraw canvas
  return False



myDraw :: Double -> Render ()
myDraw pos = do
    setSourceRGB 1 1 1
    paint
    setSourceRGB 0 0 0

    moveTo pos 0
    lineTo pos 20
    stroke
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, you could have a global.  Ignoring that solution as bad form, this looks like a job for an [MVar](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/libraries/base/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html).  In `main` you just make a new MVar which you can update in `onKeyboard` and check in `myDraw`:

```
...
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

main = do
    ...
    mv <- newMVar 0
    ....
    canvas `on` exposeEvent $ do liftIO $ renderWithDrawable draWin (myDraw mv 10)
    ...
    window `on` keyPressEvent $ onKeyboard canvas mv

onKeyboard canvas mv = do
    modifyMVar_ mv (\x -> return (x + 1))
    ....

myDraw mv pos = do
    val <- readMVar mv
    ...
```

Note that sharing mutable state is also often useful when passing functions as arguments by first using partial application to provide the `MVar` (or `TVar`, `IORef`, whatever).

Oh, and a warning: MVars aren't strict - if the application has the potential to write lots without forcing the value (i.e. reading and comparing the contained `Int`), then you should force the value before writing to avoid building a huge thunk.