# VTY-UI needs IO. Can I make this happen?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm trying to build a UI with the VTY-UI library.
I'm also using a custom monad (a few monads stacked on top of eachother).
For regular IO functions, this is not a problem. I can just lift them into my monad. However, the VTY-UI function `onActivate` has this type signature:

`onActivate :: Widget Edit -> (Widget Edit -> IO ()) -> IO ()`

Is there a way to turn a `Widget Edit -> MyMonad ()` function into a `(Widget Edit -> IO ())` without having to wrap and unwrap my monad?
I'd rather not rewrite all the library's type signatures to be `MonadIO m => m ()` instead of `IO ()`.

Comment: What is, exactly, your monad stack?

Comment: A ReaderT on top of a  StateT on top of IO

Comment: And do you need the function to return `MyMonad ()` as well? I mean, if the callback changes the state, must those changes be noticed outside the callback? Or is it ok to return `IO ()` like `onActivate` does now?

Comment: It doesn't have to return MyMonad, although that would be nice. I can lift that. It does have to accept my monad though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to implement the suggestion mentioned in the comments of the question.

I give vty callbacks in `IO` that sends events down a `Chan`. Then i have another thread listening for those events and executing the appropriate actions in my own monad.

Answer (score 3):

The function [`liftBaseOpDiscard`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#v:liftBaseDiscard) from [monad-control](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#v:liftBaseDiscard) seems to do the trick:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control 

type MyMonad a = ReaderT Int (StateT Int IO) a

onActivate' :: Widget Edit -> (Widget Edit -> MyMonad ()) -> MyMonad ()
onActivate' = liftBaseOpDiscard . onActivate
```

This function has a [`MonadBaseControl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t:MonadBaseControl) constraint, but `ReaderT` and `StateT` on top `IO` already have instances for that typeclass.

As the documentation for `liftBaseOpDiscard` mentions, changes to the state inside the callback will be discarded.

`MonadBaseControl` lets you temporarily hide the upper layers of a monad stack into a value of the base monad of the stack ([`liftBaseWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#v:liftBaseWith)) and afterwards pop them again, if needed ([`restoreM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#v:restoreM)).

**Edit:** If we need to preserve effects that take place inside the callback (like changes in the state) one solution is to "mimic" state by using an `IORef` as the environment of a `ReaderT`. Values written into the `IORef` are not discarded. The [`monad-unlift`](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/04/announcing-monad-unlift) package is built around this idea. An example:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Unlift 
import Control.Monad.Trans.RWS.Ref
import Data.IORef

-- use IORefs for the environment and the state
type MyMonad a = RWSRefT IORef IORef Int () Int IO a

onActivate' :: Widget Edit -> (Widget Edit -> MyMonad ()) -> MyMonad ()
onActivate' we f = do 
    -- the run function will unlift into IO
    UnliftBase run <- askUnliftBase
    -- There's no need to manually "restore" the stack using
    -- restoreM, because the changes go through the IORefs
    liftBase $ onActivate we (run . f)
```

The monad can be run afterwards using [`runRWSIORefT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-unlift-0.1.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-RWS-Ref.html#v:runRWSIORefT).

Comment: I'm guessing there is no way to keep the sate changes?
I'm supposed to pass 'things that happen when I press a key' to this functon.

I didn't know about this functionality though. Thank you!

Comment: @Syd Kerckhove I don't know how to do it. The problem is that the callback returns `IO ()`, so there's no way to encode the "extra stuff" needed to restore the hidden monad stack layers afterwards. Perhaps you could use a mutable reference as the state, like `Control.Monad.Trans.State.Ref` from package `monad-unlift` does. Plus, the transformers in that package are easy to "unlift" into `IO`. https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/04/announcing-monad-unlift

Comment: This looks promising. Could you write me an example? Or should I look into rewriting the vty-ui library to use MonadIO instead of IO?

Comment: @SydKerckhove [You probably will not succeed at lifting everything in `vty-ui` into `MonadIO`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9243215/791604) But [you are not the first to have to deal with state and GUI libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12002814/791604).

Comment: @Syd Kerckhove After some reconsideration, perhaps the best solution would be to use channels: make the callback write events into a `Chan` or `TChan`, and have another thread that reads events from the channel and processes them.

Answer (score 0):

For the state part: you can use this module. Thanks to whoever realized that making `get` and `put` polymorphic was a good idea.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
module IState where
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Applicative
import Data.IORef

newtype IState s m a = IState (ReaderT (IORef s) m a)

runIState (IState a) s = do
  sr <- liftIO $ newIORef s
  runReaderT a sr

runIStateRef (IState a) r = runReaderT a r

instance (Monad m) => Monad (IState s m) where
  return = IState . return
  (IState a) >>= f = let
    f' i = let (IState i') = f i in i'
    in IState (a >>= f')

instance (Monad m,Functor m) => Applicative (IState s m) where
  pure = return
  (<*>) = ap

instance (Functor m) => Functor (IState s m) where
  fmap f (IState a) = IState (fmap f a)

instance (MonadIO m) => MonadIO (IState s m) where
  liftIO = lift . liftIO

instance (MonadState s' m) => MonadState s' (IState s m)   where
  get = lift get
  put = lift . put

-- Because of this instance IState is almost a drop-in replacement for StateT
instance (MonadIO m) => MonadState s (IState s m) where
  get = IState $ do
    r <- ask
    liftIO $ readIORef r
  put v = IState $ do
    r <- ask
    liftIO $ writeIORef r v

instance MonadTrans (IState s) where
  lift a = IState (lift a)
```